# Temporarily disabling javascript function from repeating after mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery that rotates through the rotator class divs on [www.creat3dprinters.com](http://www.creat3dprinters.com) that pauses on `mouseenter` and then fires again 1 second after `mouseleave`.

However, if a user moves the mouse in and out of the rotator class div quickly the function calls stack up and the visible changes until the 'stack' is completed.

I want the 1 second delay that has not been completed to be cancelled on the 2nd and subsequent `mouseenter` so that this does not happen.

I have tried using `clearTimeout` within the `mouseenter` function but it does not seem to work.

I know there is also the `stop()` function but that did not work either.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var initList = setInterval('RotateIt()', 4000);

    $('.rotator').mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(initList);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            RotateIt()
        }, 1000);
        initList = setInterval('RotateIt()', 4000);
    })
});



function RotateIt() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    if ($('#rotator-visible').next('.rotator').length == 0) {
        $('.rotator:first').attr('id', 'rotator-visible');
        $('.rotator:last').removeAttr("id");

    } else {
        $('#rotator-visible').removeAttr("id").next('.rotator').attr("id", "rotator-visible");
    }
}
```

Comment: WTH is that nearly-half-an-hour `timeout` call supposed to do?

Comment: Do not pass strings of code to `setTimout`/`setInterval`, but functions!

Comment: apologies, that was in there because I was trying to use that as a very long setTimeout that was then cleared in `mouseenter` - now edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a user moves the mouse in and out of the rotator class div quickly the function calls stack up

Then `clearTimeout` it - and in exactly that place, not only in the delayed `RotateIt`. The simplest solution would be to call `clearTimeout` every time before `setTimeout`, so that you can be sure there is only one active timeout at once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var initList = setInterval(rotateIt, 4000),
        delay = null;

    $('.rotator').mouseenter(function(e) {
        clearInterval(initList);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(function () {
            rotateIt();
            initList = setInterval(rotateIt, 4000);
        }, 1000);
    })
});

function rotateIt() {
    if ($('#rotator-visible').next('.rotator').length == 0) {
        $('.rotator:first').attr('id', 'rotator-visible');
        $('.rotator:last').removeAttr("id");
    } else {
        $('#rotator-visible').removeAttr("id").next('.rotator').attr("id", "rotator-visible");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I was convinced I had done something like this and it did not work. Much appreciated. Excellent answer.